# How to retrieve shared link using Dropbox.Api v 2.0 client nuget library in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropbox-api

I've been working with this for hours, I have .png files inside Dropbox and I need to get a raw link to those files so I can use it within my code. How can I retrieve in C# a shared link that I have in Dropbox? I need to retrieve that link so I can use it in my view to assign it to a `src` parameter for an image. Inside my controller I'm using the `CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsArg` method which creates shared links for files, but how can I get those links after? This is my code:

```
List<Dropbox.Api.Files.Metadata> list = new List<Dropbox.Api.Files.Metadata>();
   foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var path = new Dropbox.Api.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsArg(item.PathDisplay);
}
```

I've used something like this and works good but this code throws an exception when the shared link already exists because the following code tries to create a shared link always, I've shared all the files and I just need to get the shared link within my code, how can I do this?:

```
var sharing = await client.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(path);
var src = sharing.Url;
```

I'm using Dropbox.Api v 2.0 and C#

Comment: Trying to understand what you want to achieve. Are you trying to figure out how to check if an item already exists before creating it?

Comment: @Vinod I've created already shared links for all items, I just need to get those links now in C#, I think that Dropbox.Api should have a method for it, I'm reading about `GetSharedLinkFileAsync` now

Comment: Are you using some sort of a wrapper library (nuget package) to access DropBox api?

Comment: @Vinod yes, I've installed Dropbox.Api

Comment: Looks like you may have to use ListSharedLinksAsync, Please look at its usage here https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_ListSharedLinksAsync.htm and https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_ListSharedLinksAsync_1.htm.
GetSharedLinkFileAsync appears to be deprecated.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/How-to-retrieve-shared-link-Dropbox-API/m-p/196854#M9037 ]

Comment: Vinod's correct. There's also a sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dropbox-api/414/getting-a-shared-link-for-a-file-or-folder/2415/getting-a-shared-link-for-a-file-using-the-dropbox-net-library#t=201612071822533673265